# integration of solr on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, solr

I have installed solr and indexd via curl command and have performed search activities. Now I want to deploy this on hadoop and make the indexing automatic when files are pushed to the storage directory. I am totally new to Hadoop and have no idea. So can anyone brief me on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know underlying technologies too much, you might be better off looking at vendor offerings that specialize in putting multiple packages together and provide training material around their specific combinations.

Specifically, I would recommend looking at something like [CDH from Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh.html). It includes Hadoop, Solr and many other things, such as Hue.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can make them indexing automatic when the file lands in a directory.

1. using curl - write the shell script and run it as a cron.
2. Using Oozie - create the shell action and schedule it.
3. I hope the morpline/flume solr sink might work.

Note: if you find the solutions with respect to 3, please share.

Cheers,
Kannan

Answer (score -1):

you can see Solr Reference Guide (Running Solr on HDFS)
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS

> Solr has support for writing and reading its index and transaction log files to the HDFS distributed filesystem
>
> To use HDFS rather than a local filesystem, you must be using Hadoop 2.x
>
> you will need to instruct Solr to use the HdfsDirectoryFactory. There are also several additional parameters to define. These can be set in one of three ways:
>
> 1.Pass JVM arguments to the bin/solr script. These would need to be passed every time you start Solr with bin/solr.
>
> 2.Modify solr.in.sh (or solr.in.cmd on Windows) to pass the JVM arguments automatically when using bin/solr without having to set them manually.
>
> 3.Define the properties in solrconfig.xml. These configuration changes would need to be repeated for every collection, so is a good option if you only want some of your collections stored in HDFS.